# LUKS: Use TPM to make password hash function resistant to parallellized cracking

Tags: grub2, luks, tpm

In order to do that, I think it's possible to make the password hash dependent on the TPM: that way, an attacker would need to invoke the TPM for every password hash, limiting the speed of password cracking to the speed of the TPM (alternatively, an attacker could attack the TPM itself and try to dump those keys, but let's assume this is not feasible; if it is possible, the password itself is still a protection).

This setup seems theoretically possible, but I'm wondering if it is already implemented in LUKS/grub/... today or if I would need to program this myself. If it is already implemented, please describe how to set up such a system, preferably on Arch Linux.